# gwt-test-utils UnsatisfiedLinkError on FormPanelImpl.submit()

Tags: gwt, gwt-test-utils

> I am using GWT 2.5 with GWT-Boostrap 2.2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.gwt-test-util
>   version is 0.44-SNAPSHOT

I have a **WellForm** element comprising of username and password. 
When I try to submit the form using **Browser.submit()**, it throws an error that the WellForm cannot be convert to FormPanel(which I think is an issue).
Also, if I get the loginForm instance and then explicitly call **submit()** method, I get the following error.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.FormPanelImpl.submit(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;)V

It initially seemed that the **submit()** method is not defined in the *FormPanelImplPatched.java*. I added the same and re-compiled the code. But am facing the same issue.

Other than adding the method to the PatchClass, is there any other method to solve the issue.

Comment: what is the link you set to submit ?